# Dash daq.BooleanSwitch() style misbehaving after using bootstrap

Tags: python, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

I am trying to use bootstrap in my Dash application but, while using daq.BooleanSwitch() the style of switch is misbehaving.

This is my code -

```
import dash
import dash_daq as daq
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    daq.BooleanSwitch(
        id='my-boolean-switch',
        on=False
    ),
    html.Div(id='boolean-switch-output')
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('boolean-switch-output', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-boolean-switch', 'on')])
def update_output(on):
    return 'The switch is {}.'.format(on)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Output - 
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQi5m.png)

Please help me.

Comment: any snippet of that shows your problem?

Comment: It seems like the CSS styles from Bootstrap interfere the styles of your BooleanSwitch. If you really want to use both together you will need to fix the styles yourself by creating a custom stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add in the css file `.daq-booleanswitch--light__background { box-sizing: content-box; }`  and it works :)